# how do i write the ffmpeg command line to gen a video use images which have different size and named irregularly?

Tags: android, image, video, ffmpeg

I want use images to generate a video, i found a ffmpeg  command option name '-f concat' ,anybody can give me more infomations?

i try like this:

ffmpeg -r 1/5 -s 480*480 -f concat -safe 0 -i test/b.txt -c:v libx264 test/test.mp4

but an error appear：
Option video_size not found.

Comment: Put the size option after the `-i` argument.

Comment: i add "-video_size  480*480" , but dose not work

Comment: Put the size option after the -i argument. --> `ffmpeg -r 1/5 -f concat -safe 0 -i test/b.txt -s 480x480 -c:v libx264 test/test.mp4 `